# How to handle ASCII error in move language

Tags: move-lang

I have a simple move file containing this simple code

```
address 0x2 {
    module Coin {
        struct Coin {
            value:u64,
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to  publish it, it gives me this strange error

```
    error[E01001]: invalid character
  ┌─ src/modules\coin.move:1:14
  │
1 │ address 0x2 {
found when reading file. Only ASCII printable characters, tabs (\t), and line endings (\n) are permitted.
```

Comment: I'm not sure which flavour of Move you're using but if it is Aptos, generally you start with this: `module address::module_name`, that might be your problem?